# How to disable or enable custom exception in pythonic way

Tags: python, exception

```
from ctypes import *
class MyCustomException(Exception):  # note naming convention

    MESSAGES = {
        0x00000000: 'NO ERROR',
        0x00000001: 'Error 1 occurred',
        0x00000002: 'Error 2 occurred',
        0x00000004: 'Error 3 occurred',

    }

    def __init__(self, err_num, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # handle inheritance
        self.err_num = int(err_num)
        self.err_msg = self._create_err_msg(self.err_num)

    def __str__(self):
        return "ERROR (0x%08X): %s" % (self.err_num, self.err_msg)

    def __repr__(self):
        # Note that __repr__ should be eval-able
        return 'MyCustomException(%d)' % self.err_num

    @classmethod
    def _create_err_msg(cls, err_num):
        messages = []
        for num, msg in cls.MESSAGES.items():
            if err_num & num:
                messages.append(msg)
        return ' and '.join(messages) if messages else cls.MESSAGES[0]

def some_function():
    error =0
    # do some operation then return if any error
    return error

 def test():
     disbaleexecption = 1   # I want to disable and enable exception in pythonic way, i need help here
     if not disbaleexecption:
         err = some_function()
         try:                                     # If any error occurs raise exception and catch the perticular exception and notice to the user,
                                                  # I want to do in more pythonic way, I need help on this
            raise MyCustomException(err)
         except MyCustomException as error:
            windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "My error", error, 6)
     else:
        err = some_function()                     # If disabled an exception , just print on the console , I want to do in pythonic way
        if err:
            print "error",err


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        test()
```

How to enable or disable a custom exception in `Python` and log the line number from which the exception is raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your enable/disable of how you want to handle your exceptions, is often done with having a debug "flag" in your program, for eg.

```
import sys, traceback  # Needed for pulling out your full stackframe info

debug = True
try:
    err = some_function()
except MyCustomException as error:
    if debug:
        # Print to the console
        print "error: ", error
        # To get the traceback information
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        print traceback.format_exc()
        # or
        print traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)
    else:
        windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "My error", error, 6)
```

You can take a look at the [Traceback Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) for more examples.

Comment: Excellent!! I will come back to you. But this really helps

Comment: raise MyCustomException(err), since I am writing my custom exception , I have to raise exception manually right? M new to exception handling. Requesting your help here

Comment: You would raise your custom exception in your `some_function` code based on some condition normally. So say for example you're expecting an argument to be supplied to the function, and it should be an integer, so you check the type and if it doesn't match then you raise the appropriate exception there, which then will get caught by your try/except block.

Comment: How do i put the traceback information into pthon Logger as well. Thanks in advance!!